# How to select all the divs inside selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <p> <input name="select_all" type="checkbox" value="1"> Select/Deselect All</p>

    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">
        <span><input checked="checked" name="manage_group" type="checkbox" value="1"></span>
        <span class="form-control">Create/manage groups of candidates</span
    </div>

    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">
        <span><input checked="checked" name="manage_candidate" type="checkbox" value="1"></span>
        <span class="form-control">Modify candidate details</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to Check all the checkboxes (WITHIN the parent div only) if 'select_all' checkbox is checked and uncheck all if the 'select_all' is unchecked.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(".panel-body p input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    if(this.checked){
        //alert('Checked');
        var selected = this.closest(".panel-body");
        $(selected+"div input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
            alert ('Hi');
        });
    }else{
    }
});
```

But it is not working. It is not accepting 'selected' variable inside the selector. How to select all checkboxes within the selected element?

Comment: try it like this, as selected is already a jquery selector :
`selected.find("div input[type='checkbox']")`

Comment: selected.find() doesn`t work. Uncaught TypeError: selected.find is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this line:-

```
this.closest(".panel-body");
```

where `this` is the element and not the jQuery object.

You can achieve what you want like so:-

```js
$(".panel-body p input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).closest(".panel-body");
    selected.find("div input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <p>
    <input name="select_all" type="checkbox" value="1">Select/Deselect All</p>

  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">
            <input checked="checked" name="manage_group" type="checkbox" value="1"></span>
    <span class="form-control">Create/manage groups of candidates</span>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">
            <input checked="checked" name="manage_candidate" type="checkbox" value="1"></span>
    <span class="form-control">Modify candidate details</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH @BenG, I banged my head for hours before posting it here. Not only you solved the problem, you also educated me a little more on jquery. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following. Find all `checkbox` in closest `.panel-body` and change `checked` property based on `select_all` status.

```js
$(":checkbox[name=select_all]").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('.panel-body').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
    <p> <input name="select_all" type="checkbox" value="1"> Select/Deselect All</p>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input checked="checked" name="manage_group" type="checkbox" value="1">
        </span>
        <span class="form-control">Create/manage groups of candidates</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input checked="checked" name="manage_candidate" type="checkbox" value="1">
        </span>
        <span class="form-control">Modify candidate details</span>
    </div>
</div>
```